# Make Sitecore item bucketable programmatically

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, buckets

I am generating a lot of sitecore content items programmatically in a tree structure. To provide an example, the structure looks something like this in content tree:

```
Sitecore
    content
       Item1
          SubFolder1 (containing thousands of subitems)
       Item2          
          SubFolder2 (containing thousands of subitems)
...and so on
```

Now, all the subitems within Subfolder1 use the same template, similarly other SubFolders too. I want to make all the Subfolders bucketable programmatically. I know how to do this using Sitecore UI but that's not practical in this case as there will be thousands of such subfolders. So, how do I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following namespace to use buckets extension methods:

```cs
using Sitecore.Buckets.Extensions;
```

Use the following code to create item buckets:

```cs
public static void CovertToBucketItem(Item SubFolderItem)
{ 
    Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketManager.CreateBucket(SubFolderItem);
    using (new Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext(SubFolderItem, SecurityCheck.Disable))
    {
        if (!IsBucketItemCheck(SubFolderItem))
        {
            IsBucketItemCheckBox(SubFolderItem).Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
public static bool IsBucketItemCheck( Item item)
{
    return (((item != null) && (item.Fields[Sitecore.Buckets.Util.Constants.IsBucket] != null)) && item.Fields[Sitecore.Buckets.Util.Constants.IsBucket].Value.Equals("1"));
}

public static CheckboxField IsBucketItemCheckBox( Item item)
{
    return item.Fields[Sitecore.Buckets.Util.Constants.IsBucket];
}
```

All subitems can be added to `SubFolderItem` the usual way.

```cs
SubFolderItem.Add(SubItemName,SubItemTemplate)
```

Make sure that template's `Standard Value` for Subitems have the field `Bucketable` checked.

Hope this helps.